# gcloud sdk cannot find the file by gs link

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

It is weird to see this as the result, please tell me what should I do now. 
I cannot find anything helpful through Google, please help me, thanks

When I execute the command:

```
gcloud ml speech recognize 'gs://cloud-smaples-test-01/speech/test.wav' --language-code='en-US'
```

on my computer, the only response that I can see is this:

> ERROR: (gcloud.ml.speech.recognize) Invalid audio source ['gs://cloud-smaples-test-01/speech/test.wav']. The source must either be a local path or a Google Cloud Storage URL (such as gs://bucket/object).

smaples is correct, I do change the order to avoid the same name.

However, when I execute the same command on Google Cloud Shell, I can see the result of speech to text. I do not know what happened exactly.

I use the same Google account to execute command whatever on my computer or Google Cloud Shell. I also set the file even the whole storage can be read by anyone.

What could cause this problem?

[result on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkkTM.jpg)

[result on google cloud shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLKKF.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running Windows in your computer. The problem is that Windows interprets quotation marks as part of the string.

Removing the quotes in both your bucket path and the language code tag will resolve the issue.

Example:

```
gcloud ml speech recognize gs://cloud-smaples-test-01/speech/test.wav --language-code=en-US
```

Comment: Or change ` to `"`. This way you can still use long path names.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I have never heard about that issue before. Is there any other similar problem I should take care? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know this is more of a windows ‘feature’ than an issue. I don’t think there are any other outstanding problems related to this one, but if you find any don’t hesitate to open a new question!